# keeping deleted data in other table

Tags: mysql

I want to keep the deleted data from SQLdatabase in other table for example if my main table is USER with 5 col. If user deletes his I'd I want that info in other table like Del_user with same col.. Any idea?

Comment: __Instead__ add field like `disabled` for __same__ user table.

Comment: you will need to setup 2 different connections and pick which one you need accordingly. Are you not able to just soft delete the fields with a deleted column populated by a timestamp?

Comment: If this is for GDPR, you are not allowed to keep the user data upon deletion, and not even copy it to another table either. It must be fully deleted.

Comment: As suggested by @u_mulder. That is gonna be a good idea. Baaki timro khusi 

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest an option here called *soft deletion*.  Using soft deletion, you would add a bit column to your `USER` table which would track whether the record has been logically deleted or not.  Under this approach, deleting a record does not mean physically removing it, but only marking it as deleted.  So, in your queries against `USER`, most of the time you would just also add a check on the bit column to make sure you were looking at an active record.

The potential drawback of soft deletion is that all your data, past and present, remains in a single table.  If you expect users to turn over records very often, then you could end up with an unwieldy table.  But, for something like a user table, this might not be such a big concern.

Comment: My main concern with this would be if there was a unique requirement of something like e-mail address.  It may then clash with deleted records.

Comment: @NigelRen Then we can add a unique constraint on the combination of the user ID and the email.  Then, a given user record could appear in duplicate (or more), which would be OK, so long as no other user record claims the same email address.

Comment: @SapkotaBishnu one advantage that this method has over the trigger answer it makes it more eazy to restore the "deleted" record . "The potential drawback of soft deletion is that all your data, past and present, remains in a single table. " For a larger table tables a partition on the "delete" column might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by dB trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER archive_user_before_delete BEFORE DELETE ON User
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    Insert into del_user select OLD.id, ...
  END;
```

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html